# How many 3 character combinations can be made using letters AND numbers?

Tags: combinations

I'm wondering how many possible 3 character combinations can be made using the 26 letters of the alphabet, and 0-9. I've seen that with just the alphabet you can create somewhere around 17k different combinations of 3 letters, but I assume adding in 0-9 must increase that number substantially.

Comment: Is order important to you?  you say how many 3 letter/numeral **combinations**?  so would, say, a13 and 1a3 be counted as the same code? or as 2 different codes?  When you say combination, we would assume that they are counted as the same code.

Comment: $(26+10)^3=46656$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are 36 combinations for each, and they're all independent. 36x36x36 is 46656.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we're choosing from 26 letters and 10 digits, such that the case of the letters doesn't matter and repetition is allowed, you have

$$36 \times 36 \times 36$$

arrangements, since you have 36 choices each. If letter case matters, then

$$62 \times 62 \times 62$$.

Answer (score 1):

Deusovi is correct if characters can be repeated. If not then 36x35x34 combinations are possible.